# Doctrine PHPCR - Query on ReferenceOne attribute

Tags: doctrine-odm, symfony-cmf, doctrine-phpcr

I've got a problem with doctrine phpcr and the query builder. Is it possible to do a query on an attribute with ReferenceOne() ?

e.g :

```
/**
 * @PHPCR\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="....\Program")
 */
private $program;
```

But when I'm trying to build a query on it :

```
$qb->where()->eq()->field('news.program')->literal($program->getId())->end();
```

I've got the following error

```
Cannot use association property "program" of class "...\News" as a dynamic operand.
```

Is there a way to do a query on this kind of attribute please ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **DocumentManager::getReferrers()** to do that.

https://github.com/doctrine/phpcr-odm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ODM/PHPCR/DocumentManager.php#L722

In a ContainerAware context (Controller or Fixture) :

```
/** @var \Doctrine\ODM\PHPCR\DocumentManager $dm */
$dm = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine_phpcr')->getManager();

$referrers = $dm->getReferrers($yourObject, null, null, null, 'YourBundle:ReferrersClass');
```

Here it would be :

```
$news = $dm->getReferrers($program, null, null, null, 'YourBundle:News');
```